# Send json data to Node.js with Socket.io

Tags: jquery, html, json, node.js, socket.io

I am doing a project in Node.js using socket.io technology. Here's the code I wrote in html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

    var markers = mydata.map(function (location) {
        return {
            title: location.yer,
            lat: location.lat,
            lng: location.lng
        };
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1234");
        socket.emit("test", mydata);

        socket.on("test", function (data) {

            //$("body").append("Name : " + data.value1 + ", Age : " + data.value2);
            //$("body").append("<br>");
        });

    });
```

Here is the code that I wrote on server.js on the node.js side:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

console.log("User Connected");

socket.on("test", function (data) {

    console.log("Yer : " + data.value1 + ", Lat : " + data.value2 + ", Long : " + data.value3);
});

socket.on("disconnect", function () {

    console.log("User Disconnected");
});
});
```

When I first open the html page, I get the data from the data.json file in the same folder along with the html. After fetching, I can map it to JavaScript and assign it to mydata variable. I am sending this variable to the server side of Node.js with the code that I wrote in html with jQuery. The connection to Node.js works fine, but when I send this json data to the node.js, when I print the data I send to the console, I see the message "Location: undefined, Lat: undefined, Long: undefined". I do not understand where I got a nuisance. Can you help me?

Comment: here is the json file......data = '[{"yer" : "Besiktas", "lat" : "41.044161", "lng" : "29.001056"},{"yer" : "Eminönü", "lat" : "41.017513", "lng" : "28.970939"},{"yer" : "Zeytinburnu", "lat" : "40.990828", "lng" : "28.895325"}]';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the server websocket handler receives an array of objects, but you try to parse it as if it was an object. Try this, please:

```
socket.on("test", function (data) {
    data.forEach(obj => {
        console.log("Yer : " + obj.yer + ", Lat : " + obj.lat + ", Long : " + obj.lng);
    })
});
```

Comment: **Error connecting [io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error]**